# Регулярное выражение повторения любого символа

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

132**рр**2, 2**+++**4н, ук**44**к**ллл**6.
Какое регулярное выражение поможет найти в строке наличие повторяющихся неопределенное число раз символов? Количество повторов в одной строке неважно.
Пробовал что-то такое:

```
new RegExp("^(.){2,}$");
```

Но точка находит любой симво, а не повторение одного и того же.

Comment: в js вроде нет именованных групп как в PCRE

Comment: Т.е. в javascript такую проверку сделать невозможно?

Comment: я ошибся слегка, можно вот так сделать:

    'ttttarrr'.match(/(?=(.))\1{2,}/g)

Comment: Тогда уж можно проще:  
  
   'ttttarrr'.match(/(.)\1{2,}/g  
  
Зачем "?="?

Comment: потому-что тогда придется писать {1,} вместо {2,}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. зачем в регулярном выражение вы поставили символы начала и конца (^ и $) строки?
2. выражение (.){2,} означает "найти любую последовательность символов от 2-х и более"

Ваша задача в одно регулярное выражение не решается (ну по крайней мере я такого решения не знаю, кроме как перебирать строку циклом).

[image]

[image]

Проверялось в PHPStrom, будет ли работать в JS не знаю.

UPD: \1 - обращение к тому, что было найдено в (.)

UPD 2: [Регулярные выражения - Обратная связь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9E.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D1.81.D0.B2.D1.8F.D0.B7.D1.8C)

Comment: А что означает "\1"? Я не нашел такого обозначения.

Comment: "Ваша задача в одно регулярное выражение не решается" - а почему не `\1+`?

Answer (score 12):

Можно сделать используя backreference (\1\2\3) на захваченные группы

```
 var re=/(?=(.))\1{2,}/g
          |  |  |  |_повторяется - два и более  раз
          |  |  |_первая захваченная группа  
          |  |_в первую группу любой символ
          |_ - не захватываем это совпадение, просто записываем в группу
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/kR_cuiVs5dUDIXWe)

Answer (score 3):

```
(?:a{2,})|(?:b{2,})|(?:c{2,})....(?:1{2,})|(?:2{2,})...(?:\+{2,})
```

Составляется при помощи цикла, после чего копируете и вставляете.

Решение ua6xh можно расширить для всех регэкспов, поддерживающих обратные ссылки:

```
(.)\1{2,}
```

\1 - это обратная ссылка на то, что было найдено в скобках (.) То есть, он ищет любой символ, а потом пытается понять продублирован ли он или нет.

Answer (score 0):

(\w|[+-?*])(\1)+
/1 делает ссылку на (\w|[+-?*]) и так далее до конца повторени

Answer (score -4):

На повторяющиеся 2 символа /(.)\1/
На повторяющиеся 3 символа /(.)\1\1/

Comment: Чем Вас не устроил принятый ответ, который более полный, развернутый и **правильный** в отличие от Вашего ?